# Why I am getting FALSE for "=FALSE<=100" in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am Priya from India,

I am trying to get the logic in excel formula

```
=FALSE<=100
```

`False` will be considered as `0`. if it is `0<=100` then **expected output** is `TRUE`.

But we are getting `FALSE` in the Microsoft Excel.

Why I am not getting `True`?

Comment: Why do you need `FALSE<=100`? why can't you use 0 instead of `false`

Comment: I am using "=(10>=50&10<=100)" in excel while evaluating this formula it becomes FALSE<=100. and finally returns FALSE.

Comment: @priyanandhini "&" is a concatenation operator. If you need a logical AND use: `=AND(10>=50,10<=100)`

Answer (score 2):

TRUE and FALSE can't be treated directly as numbers on Excel. However, they can be implicitly converted to numbers:

```
=(FALSE + 0) <= 100
```

Adding 0 to them does it.

Comment: Also, in a lot of formulas around, you'll see the conversion being done by either double negatives `--(FALSE)` or multiplication `FALSE*1`

Answer (score 0):

The formula you mentioned in the comment, even though it seems to return a correct result - `(10> = 50 AND 10 = <- 100) == FALSE`, is basically incorrect, because excel calculates it as follows:

1. `=(10>=50 & 10<=100)`
2. `=(10>="5010"<=100)`
3. `=(FALSE<=100)`
4. `= FALSE`

If you want the numbers to be compared, you can use the following options:

1. Use the AND function:

`=AND((10>=50),(10<=100))`

2. Multiply the comparisons and check if the result is greater than zero

`=(10>=50)*(10<=100)>0`

Comment: Yes, Now I got it. Thank you.